# How to access discord messages from main account instead of bot account

Tags: python, discord

I've got a bluetooth RGB bulb that I want to use for notifications in discord. It seems that following standard guides I would need to get an admin to add a bot account to each discord I wanted this functionality in.

Is there a way to get access to messages accessible in my main account without getting another account/bot added? I only need to be able to read out the messages so I can parse them and trigger RGB stuff.

I would prefer to do this in python if possible but other solutions are fine if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Self bots are against discord's TOS.

You can try using on_message(message) and using that to parse the message.content